# Error while using AUC for DecisionTreeClassifier - Python

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I'm trying to tune the max_depth parameter of my `DecisionTreeClassifier`. I try to use AUC (Area Under Curve) as the evaluation metric. Here is my code:

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.25)

    def max_depth_prediction(X_train, y_train, X_test, y_test, y):
        max_depths = np.linspace(1, 32, 32, endpoint=True)
        train_results = []
        test_results = []
        for max_depth in max_depths:
            dt = DecisionTreeClassifier(max_depth=max_depth)
            dt.fit(X_train, y_train)
            train_pred = dt.predict(X_train)
            print(y_train)
            print(train_pred)
            false_positive_rate, true_positive_rate, thresholds = roc_curve(y_train.astype(int), train_pred.astype(int))
            roc_auc = auc(false_positive_rate, true_positive_rate)
            # Add auc score to previous train results
            train_results.append(roc_auc)
            y_pred = dt.predict(X_test)
            false_positive_rate, true_positive_rate, thresholds = roc_curve(y_test, y_pred)
            roc_auc = auc(false_positive_rate, true_positive_rate)
            # Add auc score to previous test results
            test_results.append(roc_auc)
```

However I get an error while using it:

```
ValueError: y_true takes value in {'0', '1'} and pos_label is not specified: either make y_true take value in {0, 1} or {-1, 1} or pass pos_label explicitly.
```

I inspected my 2 vectors and they seem to be good:

```
y_train = ['0' '0' '0' ... '1' '1' '0']
train_pred = ['0' '0' '1' ... '1' '1' '0']
```

Comment: `y_train` and `train_pred` are list of strings, and they should be integers

Comment: they both are vectors that take value in {'0', '1'}.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`y_train` and `train_pred` are list of strings, and they should be integers. Try this

```
def max_depth_prediction(X_train, y_train, X_test, y_test, y):
    max_depths = np.linspace(1, 32, 32, endpoint=True)
    train_results = []
    test_results = []
    for max_depth in max_depths:
        dt = DecisionTreeClassifier(max_depth=max_depth)
        dt.fit(X_train, y_train)
        train_pred = dt.predict(X_train)
        train_pred = [int(i) for i in train_pred]
        y_train = [int(i) for i in y_train]
        print(y_train)
        print(train_pred)
        false_positive_rate, true_positive_rate, thresholds = roc_curve(y_train.astype(int), train_pred.astype(int))
        roc_auc = auc(false_positive_rate, true_positive_rate)
        # Add auc score to previous train results
        train_results.append(roc_auc)
        y_pred = dt.predict(X_test)
        false_positive_rate, true_positive_rate, thresholds = roc_curve(y_test, y_pred)
        roc_auc = auc(false_positive_rate, true_positive_rate)
        # Add auc score to previous test results
        test_results.append(roc_auc)
```

Comment: Working, made a mistake the first time I tried this. thanks.